# Missing PropertyChanged event when BindingList elements has properties changed

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, collections

I have a class `ViewModel` that has a property `MyList` of type `BindingList<Foo>`.

`ViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Foo has the property `FooProp`.

`Foo` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

ViewModel has this property:

```
public bool IsButtonEnabled
  {
    get
    {
      return MyList.Any(x=> x.FooProp!=null);
   }
}
```

I have a view with a button. The Enabled property of the button is bound to `IsButtonEnabled`.

But the button doesn't get enabled when an element of `MyList` has it's `FooProp` set. I've noticed that `ViewModel` doesn't fire a `PropertyChanged` event here. Why not? And how should I go about for the view model to notice that it's `IsButtonEnabled` property actually has changed?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code? Should all FooProps be different than null or only one?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**  Didn't notice that this was a getter and not a setter.  The point is still the same.  Simply implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface doesn't automatically add everything you need.  You need to create the method(below) that fires the event.  Then you need to call that method in the SETTER of all of your properties.

Shouldn't you fire the PropertyChanged event yourself?

```
public bool IsButtonEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return MyList.Any(x=> x.FooProp!=null);

        // assuming you named the method this
        OnPropertyChanged("IsButtonEnabled");
    }
}
```

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface only creates the event for you.  You need to fire the event from the ViewModel yourself.

If you haven't already created the method, this one normally works.  You would call this method explicitly when a property of the ViewModel changes.

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Firing the event in that getter makes no sense ;)

Comment: You are right.  Didn't even notice that it was a getter and not a setter.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel will not fire any PropertyChanged here because ViewModel's properties are not changed. The actual property that was changed `FooProp` which is a property of class Foo, not ViewModel.

In order to enable/disable the button based on the `IsButtonEnabled` functionality you will have to track all the elements of MyList and see if any changes are done. So, the following should work:

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) { /* ... */ }
    public object FooProp 
    { 
        get { return _obj; }
        set 
        {
            _obj = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FooProp");
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) { /* ... */ }

    private List<Foo> _myList;
    public List<Foo> MyList 
    { 
        get { return _myList; }
        set 
        {
            _myList = value;
            foreach(var item in _myList) 
            {
                HandleItem(item);
            }
        }
    }

    void AddItem(Foo item) 
    {
        MyList.Add(item);
        HandleItem(item);
    }
    void HandleItem(Foo item) 
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if(e.PropertyName == "FooProp")
        };
    }
    void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == "FooProp") OnPropertyChanged("IsButtonEnabled");
    }
    public bool IsButtonEnabled
    {
        get
        {
          return MyList.Any(x=> x.FooProp!=null);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in this case you need to use ViewModel.AddItem() in order to add an item to MyList (you can use MyList.Add(), but it will not fire the correct notifications then).

Also the code above is not the best way to do it - it is just an illustration of how your case should work. After you understand that you are probably going to replace the List<> to ObservableCollection<> to be able to track/handle items in your list automatically.